# Wordpress: Is there any way to run cli commands from php script?

Tags: php, wordpress, command-line-interface

I'm want to run a wp_cli command from my php script.

for example: `sudo -u www-data wp search-replace "foo" "bar" --all-tables && sudo -u www-data wp cache flush`

Is there any way to do that but from inside a php script function?

Thanks.

Comment: you could, using e.G. [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). But there will be problems with the permissions (you can't sudo) and you should never! pass any arguments to you shell. Proably you should ask for help for your real problem, and don't take the `wp_cli`-way!

Comment: You would probably to better to have a cron that runs to do that every x rather than have it callable from a web page.

Answer (score 1):

For wordpress, You can try plugin "Better Search Replace" for search-replace functionality and also i have one script in php for search and replace functionality which is you can download from "https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbizw2su90ndz9j/script.php?dl=0".